# In Overlord, would Enri survive resurrection given she's level 6 as of Volume 8?

Tags: overlord

In Yggdrasil, a player loses 5 levels on death, so since Enri is a level 6, does that suggest she could withstand resurrection?

[image]

In the New World it's stated that resurrection costs vitality and without enough, the person would turn to ash. The person also has to be willing to be resurrected. With a high enough tier spell, I'm assuming that Enri could be brought back as she currently is, especially since she'd want to return to the goblins and the village. Is there any strong evidence that should wouldn't survive resurrection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before talking about resurrection, we need to identify the cause of resurrection itself. There's 3 known spell to resurrect a dead person. 5th tier - raise dead, 7th tier - resurrection, and 9th tier - true resurrection. Each of them has their own rule for the spell itself to work.

In the wiki, it's said that 5th tier will cause a 5 level down and some life force reduction. But in my interpretation, the lose of levels itself is seen as losing life force. It's basically because the people in New World can't see their own level so that if the required level is not enough, they will turn into ash instead because if the level is lower than 1, they basically cease to be a living being.

As for 7th and 9th, not much known about it other than the penalty is lower than the lower tier spell, and only 9th tier true resurrection can cancels 9th tier insta-death spell true death.